# Piezo element microcontroller connection

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, safety, piezo

I have a "noname" piezoelement from Aliexpress:
[image]

I'd like to control it via microcontroller. Now I use this circuit to drive the piezo element:
[image]

Microcontroller ports produce PWM signals. Everything works fine, the sound is loud enough.

The questions are:

- Is this circuit reliable? (can it protect from voltage spikes).
- How can this circuit be improved?

Comment: How loud do you want it? If louder then use a step-up impedance voltage gain autotransformer coil.

Comment: No, that won't do it.  You need a gated oscillator circuit

Comment: @Scott If the GPIO are PWMable, an oscillator is not necessary.

Comment: Or if you bit-bang them fast enough (and the MCU has nothing better to do).

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 It is loud enough with this circuit. The problem is that there is not much free space on my PCB... So I'm interested if some components can be removed without loss of reliability.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I use PWM on both pins, so it works fine. My main interest is the safety of this circuit.

Comment: Unless the diodes are BAT54 or equiv, it might be not protecting the CMOS  2.5mm x 1.2mm if this is too big you are doing some things wrong

Comment: You should edit the question to ask what you want to know.  Is it if you drive the element into self resonance, will you damage the outputs if you omit the clamps?  Why make us guess?

Comment: @ScottSeidman I've edited the question, hope now it is more clear.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Thank you for your answers! I searched for BAT54 parts - so, if I use the diode array (two diodes in one SOT23), it means I need 2 * SOT23 = 2 * (2.90 mm * 1.3 mm). I think it can fit.

Comment: The diodes protect the IC from PE effects if struck but with 10k on each side , you might be able to remove the diodes., since there are diodes on each output and input. but depends on exposure.

Comment: Will the circuit in the initial question, protect the microcontroller in a scenario in which the device is power off and you drop it on the table hard enough for the piezo to generate significant voltage spikes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R1 and C1 could be removed.

C1 protects the piezo against constant DC bias (highpass filter), but if you take care of that from the firmware, you're fine: avoid having one GPIO constantly high and the other constantly low. When mute, put both GPIO at the same level. Also, ideally, when driving, you should drive each GPIO out of phase, so the average value across the piezo is 0V.

R1 is there as the resistive element of the highpass filter created by C1. It helps discharging the piezo (which is like a capacitor) when not driven. But if you removed C1, you don't need it anymore. But it also lowers the level of the sound, so if you remove it it will be louder.

Don't remove the diodes and R2, it protects your MCU from the spikes created by the piezo when there is a shock. But if your aim is just to make the circuit smaller, you can choose dual series diodes in a single SOT23 package like the very common BAT54S. This will make this much much smaller.